# undefined reference to `demo_navdata_client_init'

Tags: sdk, ar.drone

when I build AR Drone SDK , I get this error.Although I made all the configurations

```
../../Soft/Build/targets_versions/linux_sdk_demo_PROD_MODE_vlib_Linux_4.4.0-66-generic_GNU_Linux_usrbingcc_5.4.0/Navdata/navdata.o:(.data+0x80): undefined reference to `demo_navdata_client_init'
../../Soft/Build/targets_versions/linux_sdk_demo_PROD_MODE_vlib_Linux_4.4.0-66-generic_GNU_Linux_usrbingcc_5.4.0/Navdata/navdata.o:(.data+0x88): undefined reference to `demo_navdata_client_process'
../../Soft/Build/targets_versions/linux_sdk_demo_PROD_MODE_vlib_Linux_4.4.0-66-generic_GNU_Linux_usrbingcc_5.4.0/Navdata/navdata.o:(.data+0x90): undefined reference to `demo_navdata_client_release'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
generic.makefile:136: recipe for target '/home/tamercan/Desktop/ARDrone_SDK_2_0_1/ARDrone_SDK_2_0_1/Examples/Linux/sdk_demo/Build/../../Build/Release/ardrone_testing_tool' failed
make[4]: *** [/home/tamercan/Desktop/ARDrone_SDK_2_0_1/ARDrone_SDK_2_0_1/Examples/Linux/sdk_demo/Build/../../Build/Release/ardrone_testing_tool] Error 1
app.makefile:33: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:163: recipe for target 'build_app' failed
make[2]: *** [build_app] Error 2
Makefile:70: recipe for target 'linux_sdk_demo' failed
make[1]: *** [linux_sdk_demo] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/tamercan/Desktop/ARDrone_SDK_2_0_1/ARDrone_SDK_2_0_1/Examples/Linux/sdk_demo/Build'
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ubuntu 16.04 or later? Looks like AR.Drone SDK 2.0.1 is not compatible with that version. Last version I was able to compile this SDK was 14.04.

I posted this error in Parrot Developer Forum but the only answer I received is to use a previous version.

http://forum.developer.parrot.com/t/ardrone-sdk-2-0-1-compiling-linux-examples-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts/4168